# Curly brace is invalid character in Oracle Query

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I'm writing an oracle query behind the code of a button in vb.net and after commenting out lines in my WHERE clause I think the curly brace is preventing my query from working.

```
Dim sQuery As New IO.StringWriter
With sQuery
     .WriteLine("SELECT ...")
     .WriteLine("FROM ...   ")
     .WriteLine("WHERE ... ")
     .WriteLine("AND ((dateValue>={ts '2014-01-01 00:00:00'} ")
     .WriteLine("AND dateValue2<{ts '2015-01-01 00:00:00'})  ")
     .WriteLine("AND ROWNUM =1 ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why you are trying to escape the query, as it is okay without the curly brackets.

Use to_date to convert text to a date:

```
 .WriteLine("SELECT ...")
 .WriteLine("FROM ...   ")
 .WriteLine("WHERE ... ")
 .WriteLine("AND ((dateValue>= to_date('2014-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss') ")
 .WriteLine("AND dateValue2<to_date('2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss'))  ")
 .WriteLine("AND ROWNUM =1 ")
```

Comment: Well it's a different error but it's saying that "Hour needs to be between 1 and 12."

Comment: @SeanSilver: my bad. Try again please.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify this query:

```
.WriteLine("SELECT ...")
.WriteLine("FROM ...   ")
.WriteLine("WHERE ... ")
.WriteLine("AND dateValue >= '2014-01-01' ")
.WriteLine("AND dateValue2 < '2015-01-01' ")
.WriteLine("AND ROWNUM =1 ")
```

Comment: @SeanSilver: be aware that this solution depends on a specific date format setting to be set. This will maybe work on the current installation, but switching language will often break this code.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: My PL/SQL is rusty, but would it not work on any machine, with `yyyy-MM-dd` being one of the standard date formats? If I remember correctly, `dd-MM-yyyy` is machine dependent (dd-MM or MM-dd), `dd-MMM-yyyy` is default culture dependent, but `0000-00-00` sequence is always treated as `yyyy-MM-dd`. Please correct me if I'm wrong and provide a reference to the docs (other visitors may find it interesting in relation to this question).

Comment: When I run `select * from   dual where  sysdate < '2014-12-31'` here I get 'ORA-01861: literal does not match format string', so I think it does matter. Will try to find the corresponding docs.